# sometime my nestedrecycler view inside nestedscrollview do not scroll.and also while setting data it leads to frames skipping on the main thread

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

[image: Image description]

Let me tell you the whole scenario to let you know what's creating the problem.

I have a main activity which has `NestedScrollView` as top layout containing a `FrameLayout` to replace fragment.

I have *RoomFragment* which is set in this frame layout. Here I have used a `RecyclerView` which further has a `RecyclerView` inside it for each item. I have already set nested scrolling false on both the recycler views and have set smooth scrolling enabled to true on the nested scroll view. For inner recycler view, i have used shared `recycledviewpool` but problems continue to exist.

**Problem**:-
Not a very smooth scrolling and also very often the scrolling stops.
when I fetched data from API response in the model and set through adapters. Application's main-thread is overloaded with too much work and take too much time before displaying data and in the mean time the animation of progress bar also stops.

MY Main Activity's XML

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/homeBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.BottomNavigationDrawerActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsv_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation_bottom"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:focusable="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_backgound"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.app.gfgagent.utils.ArcLayout
                    android:id="@+id/diagonalLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    app:arc_cropDirection="cropOutside"
                    app:arc_height="@dimen/dp_40">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_background"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@color/textColor" />
                </com.app.gfgagent.utils.ArcLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_home_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_15">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                        android:text="@string/txt_home"
                        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_notification_img"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@mipmap/notification" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_notification_count"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_3"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_3"
                            android:background="@drawable/circle_notification"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_2"
                            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_2"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_2"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_2"
                            android:text="01"
                            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_8" />
                    </FrameLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_home_toolbar"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_30"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum=".5">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <com.app.gfgagent.custom_view.CircleImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_110"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_110"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_brown"
                                    android:padding="@dimen/dp_5"
                                    android:src="@mipmap/profile_place" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_22"
                                    android:background="@drawable/edit_draw"
                                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_5"
                                    android:drawableStart="@mipmap/profile_img_edit"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_3"
                                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp_10"
                                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp_10"
                                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_3"
                                    android:text="@string/txt_edit"
                                    android:textAlignment="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </FrameLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_20"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_wl_back"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/txt_welcome"
                            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
                            android:text="Tan Zhang"
                            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_25"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rl_backgound"


                  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_25" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_60"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_nav_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_20"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:src="@mipmap/bottom_home" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_home"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_40"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor">

                </View>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_nav_room"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_room"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:src="@mipmap/bottom_room" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_room"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_40"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_nav_sales"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_sales"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:src="@mipmap/bottom_sales_details" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_sales"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_40"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_nav_about_me"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_about_me"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:src="@mipmap/bottom_user" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_about_me"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_40"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_nav_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:src="@mipmap/bottom_setting" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_profile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_40"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>



    My Fragment's that i am replacing in frame layout in Activity   tXML

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/homeBackground"
        tools:context="com.app.gfgagent.fragment.RoomFragment">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_120"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_45"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/room_summary_notice_board">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_filter"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_120"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_45"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/dp_10">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_filter"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_5"
                        android:src="@mipmap/filter_white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/filter"

                        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/resetAll"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_room_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl_main"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_10">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </RelativeLayout>






    Single Item OF Outer RecyclerView's Adapter  XML ccontaining recyclerview.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_main_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_main"

            android:background="@color/lightHeader">


            <!--some other code-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_race_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_40"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_stroke_three_corner_top_right"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
                android:text="@string/race"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                [enter image description here][1]android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12" />



        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyler_room_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ll_table_header"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"

            ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </RelativeLayout>

My Outer RecyclerView' Adapter  JAVA CODE

public class RoomAreaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAreaAdapter.RoomAreaViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    RoomFragment roomFragment;
    ArrayList<RoomListModel.ResultBean> resultBeanArrayList;

    public RoomAreaAdapter(Context context, RoomFragment roomFragment,
                           ArrayList<RoomListModel.ResultBean> resultBeanArrayList)
    {
     this.context=context;
     this.roomFragment=roomFragment;
     this.resultBeanArrayList=resultBeanArrayList;
    }
    @Override
    public RoomAreaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_item_room_area,
               parent,false);
       RoomAreaViewHolder roomAreaViewHolder=new RoomAreaViewHolder(view);
       return  roomAreaViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RoomAreaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ArrayList<RoomListModel.ResultBean.DataBean> dataBeanArrayList=
                (ArrayList<RoomListModel.ResultBean.DataBean> ) resultBeanArrayList.get(position).getData();
            RoomTableAdapter roomTableAdapter=new RoomTableAdapter(context,roomFragment,dataBeanArrayList);
            holder.recyclerTable.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            holder.recyclerTable.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            holder.recyclerTable.setAdapter(roomTableAdapter);
            holder.recyclerTable.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        RoomListModel.ResultBean resultBean=resultBeanArrayList.get(position);
            holder.tvLocationAddress.setText(resultBean.getHouse_address());
            holder.tvRacePreference.setText(resultBean.getHouse_race());
            holder.tvPublicTransport.setText(resultBean.getTransport());

            if(resultBean.getWifi()==0)
            holder.tvWifi.setText(context.getString(R.string.No));
            else if(resultBean.getWifi()==1)
                holder.tvWifi.setText(context.getString(R.string.yes));

            if(resultBean.getSecurity()==0)
                holder.tvSecurity.setText(context.getString(R.string.No));
            else if(resultBean.getWifi()==1)
                holder.tvSecurity.setText(context.getString(R.string.yes));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resultBeanArrayList==null?0:resultBeanArrayList.size()>0?
                resultBeanArrayList.size():0;
    }
     public  void updateList(ArrayList<RoomListModel.ResultBean>
                                     resultBeanArrayList)
     {
         this.resultBeanArrayList=resultBeanArrayList;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
     }



}
```

.... Image Shows what i m doing after getting data from a service.(I am using ION REST CLIENT.)